# Why does my X1 and O1 in if case outputting as zero and not 1?

Tags: python

Anyone know why i can't get the value of this variables ?, when i check output for X1 or O1 the value didn't change and it still 0 but for count variable it show s the right output

```
def printXO1():
    global count
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        global O1
        button1.set("O")
        O1 = O1 + 1
        return O1
    else :
        global X1
        button1.set("X")
        X1 = X1 + 1
        return X1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It is not clear how you run the code, and what makes you think the values are wrong.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow. please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also see how to provide a [mre]. what is count? what is button1?